# python-weka-wrapper installing failed with error code 1 in python3.6 version

Tags: python, python-3.6

i'm installing github's python-weka-wrapper with the latest version.
i've installed other library with "pip install ___".
but i got this error code when i'm trying to install the python-weka-wrapper pkg

```
Collecting python-weka-wrapper
  Using cached python-weka-wrapper-0.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/sf/fwjdy8n10j721jhhp85cpbz40000gn/T/pip-build-xdr96_le/python-weka-wrapper/setup.py", line 41
        except HTTPError, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sf/fwjdy8n10j721jhhp85cpbz40000gn/T/pip-build-xdr96_le/python-weka-wrapper/
```

this msg keep pops in and i've edited "HTTPError, e" syntax to "HTTPError as e"
and this error aren't solved yet.
please help me!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your log output indicates that you're trying to install version *python-weka-wrapper*, which is [Python 2.7 only](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper). Instead, install [python-weka-wrapper3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-weka-wrapper3) when using Python 3.