# Problem installing weka package to python3

Tags: python, weka

I have a problem with install `weka` by `pip install python-weka-wrapper3`. (The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869703/python-weka-wrapper-installing-failed-with-error-code-1-in-python3-6-version/53502734#53502734) did not work with me).

This error appears when I am trying to run the command above:

```
Command "c:\users\nujou\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Nujou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ctvavwi1\\javabridge\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Nujou\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cdmf95_m-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Nujou\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ctvavwi1\javabridge\
```

EDIT:
the problem was:

```
"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads"
```

therefore, it is solved by downloading Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.

Comment: Is that the entire log?

Comment: no, I can't put the entire log because it is very long.

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: i found this in the last line

Comment: There is no need to compile javabridge yourself. See the installation instructions here: http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#windows